# mutate object in promise and return through promise resolve

Tags: javascript, validation, promise, variable-assignment

I'm passing an object through a bunch of validators and need to check that they all pass before resolving or rejecting a promise.

I do this by mapping through my validators, which are held in an array referencing each function `var validators = [validateId, validate...]`

Some of the validators are promises, others are not. For example validateId is simply

```
if(!this.id) this.error = 'an id must be provided';
console.log('this contains the error!', this);
return this; // I've also tried return Object.assign({},this);
```

I run the object through the validators like so:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        Promise.all(validations.map(function(validate) {
            return validate.call(view);
        })).then(function(validViews){
            console.log('no errors in this array of objects :(', validViews);
            var validView = Object.assign({}, ...validViews);
            console.log('this never has the error :(', validView);
            if(validView.error) return reject({error: validView.error});
            return resolve(validView);
        });
    });
```

My expectations was that if any of the validators returned an object with an error property, I would reject, otherwise, return the merged object.

For some reason, none of the returned objects in the `validViews` array have an error property, even though I can see the property printed in the console line within the validator function;

Comment: Can you put your complete code into JSFiddle or something like that? Thanks!

Comment: One thing I noticed in the line `validate.call(view)` is, if you are referencing the native.call method (assumption) then you might be doing it wrong. The first parameter is the value of `this` the second would be the value to pass into the `validate` function. I would also just return the `Promise.all(...).then(...)` instead of making a new promise.

Comment: the outer "new Promise" is an anti pattern you should avoid

Comment: if there really is `no errors in this array of objects` then the problem may well be in the implementation of the functions in the `validations` array - you've shown ONE, and that looks incorrect, because `this` in that function will be `view` ... as it will in every `validate` function - so, you'd be "changing" the same object (whatever `view` is, which isn't shown in the code) - there's a lot of unknowns in the code you've presented

Comment: Here's a dummy version of the code you've posted - one with an id, one without ... you can see the code you've presented works as it should - note the code in the fiddle removes the promise constructor anti-pattern, **but that is NOT the issue** https://jsfiddle.net/tddrs9fs/1/

Comment: @JaromandaX, you are correct, the issue was caused by the 'anti-pattern', however, if an error occurs, I want the promise to reject and be caught by an error, rather than return as a resolve.

Comment: `the issue was caused by the 'anti-pattern'` - actually, it's NOT the problem, and I stated as such, it's NOT the anti-pattern - it's probably code you haven't shown that is at fault

Comment: I don't know what to say, the only thing I did was remove the original promise and return the promise.all. What I think I wasn't understanding was that any error caught in the promise all would resolve as a reject. I'm looking at my tests, and they're all working.